# javascript access to text before a nested tag

Tags: javascript, html, nested-lists

If I have

```
<ul>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>Text before nested content
    <ul>
      <li>...</li>
      <li>...</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How can I access via JavaScript the only `Text before nested content` without storing it in a  element?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "without storing it in a element"?  Do you have this structure as a string, and you don't want to have to put it in the DOM?

Comment: I mean that if I have `<span>Text before nested content</span>` it is straightforward to access it (for example, in jquery, `txt=$('span').text()`), but if it is as in the example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the jQuery solution too. 
You can set a `class` or `id` of your `li` element (*anything* which will allow you to select the `element` easily) and use the following code to get the data you want:

```
$("<SELECTOR FOR LI>")
    .clone()    // clone the element
    .children() // select all the children
    .remove()   // remove all the children
    .end()      // again go back to selected element
    .text();    // get the text of element
```

For more details, please read [this article](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/). 
You can also check out this working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SVeA/1/).

**Update**

You can also do this by using `pure JavaScript`. 
Just `iterate` over the child nodes (if there is one at least), check the node type (`3`, means it's a `text node`) and if its `true`, `concat` it's text with the rest.

Here is the working example of it in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8SVeA/2/).
For more info on node types, please check out [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType).
Also, you can find useful info about `nodeType`, `nodeName` and `nodeValue` properties [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/nodetype.shtml).

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, thank you. Is there also a plain JavaScript version?

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/yBcd7/)***

You should iterate until you find nested content, then return the first childNode which will contain the text.

```
var top = document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0];
for( var child in top ){
 var c = top[child];
 if( !c.hasOwnProperty("nodeName") )continue;
 if( c.children.length > 0 ){
  alert(c.childNodes[0].textContent);
  break;
 }
}
```